# Tried to follow the instructions for testing our app on real android phone, but we need help

Tags: android

We wrote a minimal "hello" program with Eclipse on our Windows 7 Dell MT560, and it runs perfectly on the Android emulator.  Then we tried to follow the instructions on the developer.android.com web site to use USB to test the app on our phone and either the PC cannot see the phone, or we are doing something wrong. Suggestions, please?

Comment: What do you mean 'the PC cannot see the phone'?  The computer does not recognize that you have plugged in a 'device'?

Comment: What device? You'll need the Android USB driver installed, possibly your manufacturer's proprietary USB driver, and you'll need to enable USB debugging in the system settings.

Comment: We enabled debugging in the Eclipse manifest.  When we do a Run in Eclipse, no Device Choose dialog appears, we just get the emulator. I could not find a USB driver for our computer on the Dell website. Suggested links?

Answer (score 0):

If the command "adb devices" does not show you your phone that means you have no driver installed for ADB.

If you're using HTC phone you should install HTC Sync application so it will install proper driver.

Comment: We are using the LG Optimus V android phone. I tried to find a driver to install, but not having any luck. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You phone needs to be setup for USB debugging. Settings->Applications->Development->USB Debugging. Turn on USB debugging and connect your phone to your PC. Go into Eclipse and activate the DDMS perspective Windows->Open Perspective->DDMS. From there you should see your phone.

If you can't see you phone in DDMS please come back and post your phone model and actual errors or behavior.

Comment: DDMS did not show the device, even though the phone shows USB connected.  The phone is an LG Optimus V. No errors on the PC or the phone. Thanks in advance for any further suggestion.

Comment: The DDMS error message: Device monitor adb connection error: an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try to copy the application package (apk extension) to the memory of your phone and install it manually

Comment: It seems that it is connected for copying, but which folder on my phone do I copy the apk to??

Comment: Use a file manager to locate the apk. Then, just touch it and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the phone myself but this links purports to tell you how to load the drivers automatically using the SDK Manager:

[how_to_take_screenshots_on_the_lg_optimus_v](http://www.knowyourcell.com/lg/lg-optimus-v/optimus-v-guides/790159/how_to_take_screenshots_on_the_lg_optimus_v.html)

This site claims to have a link to the driver if you want to do it explicitly:

[www.lg-phones.org/lg-optimus-v-driver-download](http://www.lg-phones.org/lg-optimus-v-driver-download.html)

All at your own risk I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue w/ my LG Optimus V and Windows 7 64bit w/ Eclipse Indigo.

1. Enable USB Debugging on the Device - (Settings>Applications>Development>USB Debugging)
2. Disconnected the phone from the pc
3. Install drivers from here http://www.lg-phones.org/lg-optimus-v-driver-download
4. Reconnected the device, wait for Windows to install things automatically.
5. Choose Run from Eclipse, which launches the Android Device Chooser. The device should now be there, if not wait a few seconds and it should appear.