# Still no solution for sending android app from Win 7 to LG Optimus V

Tags: android

We have a Dell MT560 running Windows 7 with Eclipse, JDK, and the Android SDK.  At the other end of the USB cable is an LG Optimus V Android phone.  We wrote a tiny app and all it does is display "Hello Ron".  This works perfectly on the emulator, but we are having no success sending the app to the phone.  The phone does state that the USB connection is successful.  Windows Explorer does see the phone, because it treats the phone as an "I:" disk drive, and shows in Windows the folders that exist on the phone.  But DDMS on Eclipse does not list the phone as a connected device.  The docs on developer.ansdroid.sdk instruct us to do a "Run" and that then a Device Chooser dialog should appear where we can choose to run the app on the phone arther than the emulator, but that does not happen.  We have edited the Eclipse manifest to indicate "Debuggable=True".  We also upgraded the BIOS on our Dell to the latest version, "A06".  Not sure what else to try.  Four people kindly responded to my post earlier today, and we tried all their suggestions, to no avail.

Hopefully, someone out there can help figure out what mistakes we are making, please. 
Or if someone wants to walk us through it on the phone, that would be even better.
Regards,
Ron and Diane

Comment: did you enable debugging on your phone? have you installed usb drivers? http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tried to follow the instructions for testing our app on real android phone, but we need help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394281/tried-to-follow-the-instructions-for-testing-our-app-on-real-android-phone-but-w)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Point of SO etiquette: Please don't repost questions just because you haven't gotten an answer that works for you yet. You should clarify your question in your original post if you have anything to add, or add a bounty; you won't get more or better answers by spamming SO with multiple identical questions.

Comment: We did enable debugging on the phone.  The usb drivers is a different can of worms.  I used the oem-usb link to the LG site and tried to run the .msi file and that did not seem to help, but do I need a USB driver if my Dell can view the folders on the phone?

Comment: Yoni: we take offense to your use of the word spamming. We have a genuine problem and our additional post summarizes what we have tried so far, in an attempt to save SO readers time. If you took the time to compare the two posts, you would indeed see that the posts were not identical.

Comment: The point is to keep all information with the original question, not add an additional post. It actually makes it harder to give help when we don't see all of the original context.

Comment: To rephrase what Yoni said, questions on StackOverflow are meant to be long-lived reference information.  It's great if you can add more details after initially asking a question, but rather than posting a second question, you should click the "edit" link in your original question and make the changes there.  Some questions are even edited long after they're first asked.

Comment: We take offense to you expecting us to solve your problem when you won't conform to the expected guidelines. As Yoni said, you just add to the original post, not add another question.

Comment: How would we change the USB mode?

Comment: tell us if you solve this, and remember to mark as accepted the answer down there if it was the solution (click the tick mark next to the answer)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to put the phone into debug mode:

Settings - Applications - Development - USB debugging - enable it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

1) Delete the already existing emulator on eclipse. By doing this, it will surely prompt for the device to Run when you connect your phone via usb and try to run the project.

2) Export the application as an .apk file. This can then be installed after transferring the file to the phone.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble and I found a kind of solution

1. Enable your cellphone in debugging mode
2. Download the driver in the next link 
   http://www.lg.com/us/mobile-phones/mobile-support/mobile-lg-mobile-phone-support.jsp
   If you do not find the driver try to download something similar(it was my case... I have a LG-
   E425 and I downloaded the driver for LG-E739 device).
3. Connect your cellphone in your PC and then execute the driver
4. Delete the already existing emulator on eclipse
5. Run your project and if all is ok eclipse will recognize your device

I wish this steps can help you

Sorry for my English